# Data type client side validation not working in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, date, data-annotations, client-side-validation

We have an attribute called DateReleased for which the following Data Annotation attributes are added

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter date")]
[DisplayName("Date Released")]
public object DateReleased { get; set; }
```

Following is the Action which is implemented to insert a new record to the database

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Id")] Movie movie)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _entities.AddToMovies(movie);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have enabled the client validation, by placing the following lines of code in the create view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

But I was surprised to find that only Required validation is firing on client side. Data Type validation of Date is only firing at server side. Please let me know the reason behind the failure of client side validation and what would be workarounds to fire the client side validation.

Comment: If you really need lots of client-side validation, I suggest you upgrade to MVC3, which has much better jquery.validate based validation.  It's a lot less cumbersome, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Add a custom attribute class as below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DateAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    public DateAttribute() : base(DataType.Date) { }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        if (ErrorMessage == null && ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ValidatorResources.DateAttribute_Invalid;
        }
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;
        DateTime retDate;
        return DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(value), out retDate);
    }
}
```

Create Client Validation Rule class

```
public class ModelClientValidationDateRule:ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public ModelClientValidationDateRule(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "date";
    }
}
```

Create an adapter class which hooks in the custom attribute and client validation rule as below. Make sure of adding refernce of the above attribute class

```
public class DateAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<DateAttribute>
{
    public DateAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, DateAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute) { }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationDateRule(ErrorMessage) };
    }
}
```

Then modify the global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DateAttribute), typeof(DateAttributeAdapter));
}
```

Adding the Attribute to the model class as below

```
[Date]
public object DateReleased { get; set; }
```

Adding following client side code in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators["date"] = function (rule) {
    // initialization code can go here.
    return function (value, context) {
        if (value.length > 0) {
            var d = new Date(value);
            if (!isNaN(d))
                return true;
            return rule.ErrorMessage;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    };
};
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 3):

The DataTypeAttribute does not do validation.  It's really only used for selection of Editor/DisplayTemplates (and thus controls how data is formatted), and also for formatting selection within generic templates.

I'm not sure why you thought this did any kind of validation, but it doesn't.  What does control validation is the actual data type.  Since you created your data item as `object`, it can't do any vlidation of date format.  Instead, make your properties type DateTime? or Nullable

Comment: I have re-defined these attributes to the partial class generated by the ADO.Net Entity Framework. I have even replaced the object with DateTime, but the Validation didn't work. I need to do a Valid Date validation on client side.

Comment: @suryakiran - If your property type is DateTime?, it will validate that it's in a valid date format, but not that it's a valid date for your purposes.  If you need to validate that the date is within some range, then you'll have to write your own attribute.  Also, you will need to write custom date validation javascript to work with the client-side validation. See http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx